# What is the shortest path in a graph that consists of exactly one vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

I tried to find the answer to this question but either it makes no sense asking about paths in a one-vertex graph or I misinterpreted the found results so far.

I assume it would be the vertex itself but any clarification would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by the shortest path to make this a meaningful statement (e.g. are you looking for the shortest path between any pair of vertices in the graph?).

The shortest path in *any* graph is either the empty path or a path consisting of a single vertex or a single edge (depending on your definition of path, in particular whether it can be empty or whether it can contain no edges). Also, if you are just looking for any "shortest path" in a graph, then the shortest path in *any* graph is either the empty path/the path on a single vertex/edge (again depending on your definition of a path).

In general there won't be much literature on this since it's not likely considered interesting or useful information. In other words, it is considered too obvious that the shortest path oin a graph with a single vertex is the empty path/the path consisting of only that vertex. Formally, it is *trivial information*.